# How to I show recently viewed products on magento CMS page?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cms-block

Can anybody Help me with this please:

`frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/reports/recent-products-view.phtml`

I tried this below example but not working

`{{block type="reports/product_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"}}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that isn't working, another method is to use a widget:

```
{{widget type="reports/product_widget_viewed" page_size="5" template="reports/widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml"}}
```

`page_size` is the number of products you wish to display.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{block type="block/type_here" template="reports/recent-products-view.phtml"}} // you have to change `block/type` with your custom one
```